# How to display RDLC charts in MVC without using ASPX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2012, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have a line graph created using Reporting in MVC. But unable to display it using Views. Can someone please help me on how to display rdlc charts in MVC?

Comment: You can't do it without WebForms libraries (So you should add them to project anyway). But if you don't need to interact you can render it as a file (exel for example) and download.

Comment: Thanks teo van kot ..

Comment: @teovankot :  I found a way here  https://reportviewerformvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started  but its not working for me. It says system.web.mvc.htmlhelper dynamic does not contain a definition for 'Report Viewer'..I tried adding namespaces, but still not working

Comment: If you check dependences it uses `MicosoftReportViewerWebForms_v11` so it's webforms component. If you need help with install - create another question with all the details

Comment: @teovankot: I have already installed this in my project, But still there is an issue using report viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a different approach... for me, it worked.
The first thing you will need to do is:

```
 Add -> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms by Microsoft

***make sure that all the packages are in the 16 version.***
```

With this package you will only need to add the report, add a dataModel and then bind it to the report dataSet, you will no longer need to have a viewForm.

In this approach you will use the controller for:

```
   .add data (example):

EmpresaEntities emp_entities = new EmpresaEntities(); 
            ReportDataSource emp_datasource = new ReportDataSource("Empresa", (from empresa in emp_entities.FourAll_Empresa select empresa));
            viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(emp_datasource);

   . merge data(exemple):

MergeModels models = new MergeModels();
            models._Empresas = (from FourAll_Empresa in emp_entities.FourAll_Empresa select FourAll_Empresa).ToList();
            models._Entidades = (from FourAll_Entidade in ent_entidade.FourAll_Entidade select FourAll_Entidade).ToList();

   .define the size of a window(example):

viewer.SizeToReportContent = false; 
            const int ConstantePercentagem = 100;
            viewer.Width = Unit.Percentage(ConstantePercentagem);
            viewer.Height = Unit.Pixel(800);
            viewer.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage;



     .return viewer(exemple):



ViewBag.ReportViewer = viewer;
            return View( models);
```

this will set your report ready with data :)

In the Index.cshtml:

```
@using ReportViewerForMvc;
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
@using System.Web.Mvc;


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}



@Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, new { scrolling = "yes", Width = "1200px", Height = "800px" })
```